# A question about an explanation for $f^{-1}(\{y\})=\{f^{-1}(y)\}$

Tags: calculus

In a textbook, I'm asked what is the relationship between $f^{-1}(y)$ and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ if $f$ is a function with inverse $f^{-1}$, and $y \in Range(f)$? I was wondering if "is the unique element thereof" is necessary in the author's explanation (for the purpose of turning the explanation into a proof)?

> The symbol $f^{-1}(y)$ denotes the unique element $x \in Domain(f)$ such that $f(x)=y$. This element is unique since if $f(x')=y$, $$x'=f^{-1}(f(x))=x.$$

> Likewise, $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ denotes the set of $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. By above, $$f^{-1}(\{y\})=\{x\}.$$

> Therefore $f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(\{y\})$, and is the unique element thereof. We can write this as $f^{-1}(\{y\})=\{f^{-1}(y)\}$

Comment: You need $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ to have only one element, otherwise there may be other elements in there other than $f^{-1}(y)$.  Look at what happens when $f$ fails to be injective and you only have a one-sided inverse.

Comment: I thought that that was taken care of in the beginning with "the symbol $f^{-1}(y)$ denotes the unique element $x \in Dom(f)$ such that $f(x) = y$"?

Comment: Well, it is if you interpret it that way.  But the author is stating the result where he wanted to use it, and it is good style (imagine you are reading a long proof that may take a whole chapter in a book, and around 30 pages into it the author use a result from page 12 without stating).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are taking about $f^{-1} (y) $ for each $y\in Range(f) $, $f^{-1} $ means there as function, as by definition of a function , it takes each value uniquely to an another value. And , that's why, then $ f $ need to be bijective map from domain to it's range .
But Whenever you are taking about $f^{-1} (\{y\}) $ , then it's just a preimage of the set $ \{y\} $, for this $ f $ need to be just a relation.
So, in general, $f^{-1}(\{y\})=\{f^{-1}(y)\}$ is not possible.
For example , take $ f = x^2 $ on $\mathbb{R} $, clearly as $ f $ is not bijective, so, $f^{-1} (1) $ is not possible! But, $f^{-1} (\{1\}) = \{-1,1\} $.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot write  $a\in a$ as its forbidden, but $a \in \{a\}$.

Comment: He did not.  It was a case of forgotten backslash (as you can see from the edit log)

Comment: @user10354138. It changes so many times, that now I just do not know what to do. Delete it? Wait? and how to look to edit log?